# Program continues to read from redirected stdin after EOF

Tags: c, unix, stdin, eof

My program is supposed to read unix command from file, execute it, save result to file. If I simply try to run it from console, there is no problem with execution. If I redirect input to file, however, it for some reason continues to read forever. I think I might not be detecting EOF properly, but this approach seemed to work before.

I tried debugging and results are really strange. or example for a file with input

```
echo blablabla
true
false
```

it's input lines will be, in order

```
echo blablabla
true
falseecho blablabla
```

As if it read the stdout? Or stdin? But it works if I simply provide input from console.

```
FILE* script;
script=freopen(argv[argc-1], "r", stdin);
if(script==0){
  printf( "Error 1\n" );
  return 1;
}
int c;

while((c=fgetc(stdin))){
    if(c==EOF || c==4 || c<0){
        c='\n';
        exitLoop=true;
    }
    if(c!='\n'){
        inLine[i]=c;
        inLine[i+1]=0; //shouldn't be needed, but just in case
        i++;
    }else{
        inLine[i]=0;
        printf("inLine: %s i:%d\n\n",inLine,i);
        sleep(1);
        int result= 0;
        result= fork();
        if(result<0){
           printf("Failed creation of a new process. Most likely not enough memory\n");
           return 1;
        }else if(result==0){
           short int ak=childFunction(inLine,logPath,searchPath);
           return ak;
        }else if(result>0){
           int status=0;
           int d=(int)waitpid(result,&status,0);
        }else
           return -1;
        }
        i=0;
        if(exitLoop==true)
        break;
    }
}
```

edit:

```
int childFunction(char in[],char logPath[], char searchPath[]){
FILE *logFile= fopen( logPath, "a" );
if(logFile==NULL)
return 1;
char** argv;
int stringCount=1;
char* path;
int i=0,j=0;
for(i=0;in[i]!=0;i++){
    if(in[i]==' ' || in[i]=='\t'){
        in[i]=0;
        stringCount++;
    }
}
argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(stringCount+1));
i=0;
argv[0]=in;
j++;
while(j<stringCount){
    if(in[i]==0){
        argv[j]=in+i+1;
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
argv[stringCount]=NULL;
int processId=fork();
if(processId<0){
    printf("Error while forking.\n");
    exit(1);
}else if(processId==0){
    return execv(in,argv);
}
int c=0;
waitpid(processId,&c,0);
c=errno;
fprintf(logFile,"%d: %s\n", c, in);
fclose(logFile);
free(argv);
if(c!=0)
return(1);
else
return(0);
}
```

Comment: typical `char c`. Added to code

Comment: It needs to be an `int`.

Comment: Why are you checking `if (c == 4)`? You should be checking for `EOF` only. Character #4 is not special. (It is typically the EOF character for cooked mode terminal processing, but that's only relevant to the tty driver.)

Comment: What is the code for `childFunction()`?

Comment: 4 is End of Transmission. I use it to debug program from console input, instead of using files.

Comment: Added more code. The problem doesn't seem to be that program doest not detect EOF if c==EOF, but that it never reads EOF. As in, such character is never put from stdin to my variable.

Comment: Maybe check for `feof(stdin)` instead.

Comment: Nope. I tried checking if it's stream fault, but if I try to read the whole stdin before, it returns proper input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. No idea what caused the problem. I did manage to go around it however, by reading the length of file beforehand, and simply exiting the loop after x characters were read.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not `char`.  Since you want to be able to read any `char` (i.e. any byte) `fgetc()` will return the `unsigned char` value that was entered. `EOF` is defined as being less than 0, so that it can be distinguished.

You need to define `c` as an `int` so that you can identify the `EOF`, otherwise it will overlap with some valid character's value and as you discovered may not be detectable at all (if `char` is unsigned).

Comment: Tried. Not working. Edited code in original post. I'm now debugging, hoping that maybe reason has changed?

Comment: Nope. Still the same problem. It's as if it didn't read EOF at all, and for some reason started reading file again. And again. And again.